# Good or bad practice? Redirecting to stderr?

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, stderr

Straight to the point, I have a script that will `read` user input and interactively prompts before printing the final output which is expected to be obtainable by the calling user like so:

```
AVAR=$(myscript arg1 arg2 arg3)
```

So I came up with a dirty[?] hack[?] in myscript:

```
# ... blah ...
echo -n "A prompt for the user " >> /dev/stderr
read SOMEVAR >> /dev/null
# ... other stuff ...
printf "Results\t$RESULT\n"
```

Is this some sort of evil, bad practice using stderr or am I just being resourcefully sly? Excuse my ignorance, I'm 100% self-taught so I'm using deductive reasoning, ie, everything I don't want in the caller's variable must be redirected, but in the case of prompts, it still needs to be displayed, and stderr was are I could come up with.

Comment: It is usually bad practice to prompt the user. Why would you want to do that instead of having the user provide the input as an argument? That will both solve your redirection issue and allow your script to be automated.

Comment: It's also a bad practice to redirect `stdout` to `stderr` with `>> /dev/stderr` instead of the common `>&2`.  Many systems don't even have a `/dev/stderr`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Thank you so much for bringing that to my attention. I actually don't recall much about those caveats so I'm going to have another read through the basics now, before I mess anything up.

Comment: @terdon The idea I was going for was a re-usable fragment for scripts where I could, say prompt the user with multiple questions and have the results returned in a single call, that's why I need prompts (reinventing the wheel).

Comment: @nonzyro that's no reason to prompt the user. Prompting for anything more than a single character is risky since typos are very easy and a pain in the neck since your user can't repeat the same command but needs to laboriously type out their input every time. There are valid use cases but, in my experience, 9 times out of 10 when you think of prompting, you shouldn't.

Comment: @rudimeier yes, there are some (few) valid cases. Usually though, asking your users to type out your script's input is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @terdon Actually, typos are why you should *not* prompt for a single char and why many utils, eg APT, insist you type "yes" for some very critical changes. Still your argument isn't without merit from a UX POV, but since I'm the one who will be giving the input, it doesn't really apply to me. I would use a more user-friendly adaptation (eg: special character sequences like "::undo::" to undo a field) for interactions with users other than myself & co.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: Yes, this is bad practice.
Thanks @SatoKatsura for filling in the blanks.

The correct thing to do is:

```
# ... blah ...
echo -n "A prompt for the user " >&2
read SOMEVAR >> /dev/null
# ... other stuff ...
printf "Results\t$RESULT\n"
```

Which is portable and better, safer practice.

Comment: Just curious. Why redirect any output at all? I mean this snippet works fine without the `>&2` and without `>> /dev/null` for that matter. In what use case is that necessary?